# Historic average in Pandas/Numpy

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Panda dataframe (df):

```
2013-01-01   7
2013-01-02   4
2013-01-02   8
2013-01-08   8
2013-01-11  10
2013-01-12   7
```

Based on these numbers (actually school-grades), I would like to plot a graph that depicts the historic average.

Desired output:

```
2013-01-01   7.000000
2013-01-02   6.333333
2013-01-03   6.333333
2013-01-04   6.333333
2013-01-05   6.333333
2013-01-06   6.333333    
2013-01-07   6.333333
2013-01-08   6.750000
2013-01-09   6.750000
2013-01-10   6.750000
2013-01-11   7.400000
2013-01-12   7.333333
```

`df.expanding().mean()` gives me:

```
2013-01-01  7.000000
2013-01-02  5.500000
2013-01-02  6.333333
2013-01-08  6.750000
2013-01-11  7.400000
2013-01-12  7.333333
```

which is something that comes near but I want the dates in between.

If I do a `resample` on the interval of `1d` (ie. `df.expanding().mean().resample("1d").mean()`), I get this:

```
 2013-01-01  7.000000
 2013-01-02  5.916667
 2013-01-03       NaN
 2013-01-04       NaN
 2013-01-05       NaN
 2013-01-06       NaN
 2013-01-07       NaN
 2013-01-08  6.750000
 2013-01-09       NaN
 2013-01-10       NaN
 2013-01-11  7.400000
 2013-01-12  7.333333
```

The problem here is the not-unique index (two times 2013-01-02). (The NaN can be fixed :-))

How do I get the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Resampler.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.last.html) for last value of duplicated datetimes and then replace missing rows by forward filling:

```
s = df.expanding().mean().resample("1d").last().ffill()
print (s)
2013-01-01    7.000000
2013-01-02    6.333333
2013-01-03    6.333333
2013-01-04    6.333333
2013-01-05    6.333333
2013-01-06    6.333333
2013-01-07    6.333333
2013-01-08    6.750000
2013-01-09    6.750000
2013-01-10    6.750000
2013-01-11    7.400000
2013-01-12    7.333333
Freq: D, Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: That is brilliant! Thanks!

Comment: @jezrael , pls chk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569194/how-to-update-some-of-the-rows-from-another-series-in-pandas