# How to update some of the rows from another series in pandas using df.update

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df like,

```
    stamp   value
0   00:00:00    2
1   00:00:00    3
2   01:00:00    5
```

converting to time delta

```
df['stamp']=pd.to_timedelta(df['stamp'])
```

slicing only odd index and adding 30 mins,

```
odd_df=pd.to_timedelta(df[1::2]['stamp'])+pd.to_timedelta('30 min')
#print(odd_df)
1  00:30:00
Name: stamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

now, updating df with odd_df,

as per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) it should give my expected output.

expected output:

```
df.update(odd_df)
#print(df)
    stamp   value
0   00:00:00    2
1   00:30:00    3
2   01:00:00    5
```

What I am getting,

```
df.update(odd_df)
#print(df)

    stamp   value
0   00:30:00    00:30:00
1   00:30:00    00:30:00
2   00:30:00    00:30:00
```

please help, what is wrong in this.

Comment: Just update the series `df['stamp'].update(odd_df)`

Comment: but in the documentation, updating df with series not series with series, can you explain

Comment: hi bharath, did you check?

Comment: more probably a bug in dealing with timedeltas

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
df.loc[1::2, 'stamp'] += pd.to_timedelta('30 min')
```

This ensures you update just the values in DataFrame specified by the .loc() function while keeping the rest of your original DataFrame. To test, run df.shape. You will get (3,2) with the method above.

In your code here:

```
odd_df=pd.to_timedelta(df[1::2]['stamp'])+pd.to_timedelta('30 min')
```

The odd_df DataFrame only has parts of your original DataFrame. The parts you sliced. The shape of odd_df is (1,).

Comment: thanks for the answer, just see the df.update documentation, there also same type of shape is used (3,2) and (2,) and why it is not working for me?

Comment: I have tried debugging for a bit and have narrowed the issue down to the hunch that your original code isn't working because pd.to_timedelta() isn't playing well with pd.update(). I made some a similar change to your 'value' column instead (used the same slicing operation):  `change_value_df=df[1::2]['value'] + 100` and pd.update() works as it should.